# Using Web Proxy Portlet to integrate external web-application

Tags: integration, liferay, portlet, liferay-6, websphere-7

I am trying to embed an external web application in Liferay portal using [web proxy portlet](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Web+Proxy+Portlet). [Documentation](http://www.liferay.com/documents/guest/Whitepapers/Technical%20-%20Architect/Liferay%20Application%20Integration%20Strategies.pdf) (under "WEB PROXY INTEGRATION") says:

> links in an  embedded application that are served via the Web Proxy
>   portlet are automatically re-written, such that when clicked, the user
>   is not taken out of the portal context.

I want the same thing in my portlet. I want it to stay right inside the portlet window after clicking any link. But, this whole URL rewriting thing is not working. For example when I click on a button, which submits an HTTP form, I get the following error and that too on a new page

```
Error 404: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri: /liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1-20120106155615760.war/pbhs/eDJwyo10G037pWyJ1/login.form
```

"*liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1-20120106155615760.war*" is the name of Liferay portal .war file deployed on WAS v7.0

The HTML form in external application looks like this

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="/login.form" name="LoginPage">
```

Am I missing something here. Are there additional configurations/settings I need to done here. How can I achieve this ?. Any help/Links are appreciated.

**[EDIT]** : I just saw web.xml in liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1-20120106155615760.war file and found following entry :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Portlet Bridge Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pbhs/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My URL contains has "pbhs" in it. Any idea why is it saying that "*No target servlet configured for uri*" (see exception above).

***Environment:*** *WebSphere Application Server v7.0, Liferay Portal 6.1.0*

Comment: you got not soo much help :( now, i'm facing the same problem - you got some solution? If yes, please answer your own question - seems than liferay community here is not very {help/power}ful... ;(

Comment: @jm666 It has been ages ... can't remember much ..Sorry